# Override print function in child class from parent class

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know if there is a way to override the builtin print function in python 3.x used in a child class from the parent class? Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "override the builtin print function in python 3.x used in a child class"? `print` isn't a method. Do you mean `__str__`?

Comment: What parent class? Python is a functional-ish language, so yes you can override any function you want. `print = lambda x:"This function returns this string"`

Comment: for example:
class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        builtins.print('inside init')
        self.abc = 1
    def print(self):
        builtins.print('inside print')
    def __str__(self):
        builtins.print('inside str')
        self.print()       
        
class b(a):
    def __init__(self):
        super(b,self).__init__()
    def a_on(self,log):
        print('inside b')

    
n = b()
>>> inside b
I want to override the print from the class b in class a so that "inside print" gets printed instead

Comment: In python 3.6.5 in builtins.py:
def print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None): # known special case of print
    """
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
    
    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
    """
    pass

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

1. I was not able to find the real definition of `builtins.print`, but here is how I would override:

```
class ViewSpy:
    last_message = ""
    
    def print(self, *args, sep=' ', end='\n'):
        self.last_message = sep.join(map(str, args)) + end
```

To change the behavior of `v.print` based on the boolean:

```
import builtins

# ... set should_unittest variable here 

if should_unittest:
    v = ViewSpy()
else:
    v = builtins
v.print("nothing")
```

Implementation by `ViewSpy` simulates `builtins.print`, and it stores the output to a field, so that we can test it automatically.

```
def test_view_spies():
    v = ViewSpy()
    v.print("nothing")
    assert v.last_message == "nothing\n"

    v.print("something")
    assert v.last_message == "something\n"

    v.print("John", "Smith")
    assert v.last_message == "John Smith\n"

    v.print("apples", 24, "grapes", "bananas", sep=',')
    assert v.last_message == "apples,24,grapes,bananas\n"

    v.print("Automated testing is fun", end='!!!')
    assert v.last_message == "Automated testing is fun!!!"

    v.print("Maybe, you don't need a new line", end='')
    assert v.last_message == "Maybe, you don't need a new line"
```

---

2. Given the Presenter

```
class Presenter:
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view

    def present_sentence(self, response_model):
        self.view.print(*map(self.__convert_container_to_str, response_model))

    @staticmethod
    def __convert_container_to_str(each_character_as_array_element):
        return "".join(each_character_as_array_element)
```

Now we can read what `p.present_sentence` would send to the console and test it automatically

```
def test_present_sentence():
    view = ViewSpy()
    p = Presenter(view)
    p.present_sentence(({'ь', 'е', 'с', 'Д', 'В', 'л', 'а'}, {'М', 'у', 'и', 'р', 'а', 'н'},
                        {'п', 'х', 'к', 'у', 'т', 'о', 'л', 'а', 'с'},
                        {'и', 'д', 'н', 'ч', 'у', 'з', 'ж', 'о', 'л', 'а', 'с'}, {'х', 'у', 'т', 'а', 'м'},
                        {'в', 'е', 'с'}, {'в', 'е', 'и', 'ж'}, {'в'}, {'х', 'т', 'i', 'а'}, {'в', 'о', 'з', 'н'},
                        {'и', 'л', 'ж', 'о'}, {'п', 'ь', 'и', 'р', 'н', 'к', 'у', 'о', 'л', 'с'},
                        {'ш', 'i', 'у', 'з', 'о', 'л', 'а', 'м'}, {'i', 'г', 'н', 'з', 'о', 'л', 'а', 'м'}))

    printed_words = view.last_message.split()
    first_word = view.last_message.split()[0]
    assert len(printed_words) == 14

    assert len(first_word) == 7
    for letter in first_word:
        assert letter in {'ь', 'е', 'с', 'Д', 'В', 'л', 'а'}

    assert view.last_message[-1] == '\n'
    assert view.last_message[13] != ' '
    assert view.last_message[14] == ' '
    assert view.last_message[15] != ' '

    third_word = printed_words[2]
    assert len(third_word) == 9
    for letter in third_word:
        assert letter in {'п', 'х', 'к', 'у', 'т', 'о', 'л', 'а', 'с'}
```

in `__init__.py` we write the following code to actually print messages into the console, and don't store logs.

```
import builtins

#...

p = Presenter(builtins)
```